# Mixing form and layout tags in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have a form (Rails) and want to separate the submit into a separate DIV from the form fields:

```
.row
  .span
    = form_for [@household, @payment], do |h|
      %fieldset
        = h.label :lastname
        = h.text_field :lastname
        -# etc etc

  .span
    = h.submit "Submit"
```

Haml indentation rules say the "submit" tag has to be 2 spaces from the ".span".  But this breaks the form, which expects it to be indented on the same level as the "%fieldset".

How can I make this form split itself over two DIVs?

Comment: Are you seriously intending to create `<div class="span">` in your output? :/

Comment: Heh no, that was a typo.  I was trying to add a "span4" from the Twitter Bootstrap framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to put your submit outside the fieldset:

```
.row
    = form_for [@household, @payment], do |h|
        %fieldset.span
            = h.label :title
            = h.text_field :title
            -# etc etc

        .span
            = h.submit "Submit"
```

BTW, if you think that there isn't possible way to make you template more concise then take a look at [slim](http://slim-lang.com/).

Comment: Yes indeed sir, that does what I want.  Thank you!  (Now to wrangle some CSS)

Comment: There is even more concise template system: http://slim-lang.com/ -- worth trying. A year ago I thought that nothing could beat Haml :)

Comment: What are your favourite reasons for slim as opposed to HAML?

Comment: I don't like to mix few template systems in one app so when I deal with Haml-flavored app I definitely stick with Haml. If I start something new -- slim is my choice. The reasons I started to use it: 1) support of CoffeScript out of the box (Haml need additional filter); 2) no "%" at the beginning (I often forget about them); 3) more readable templates; 4) amazing Logic Less mode.